# Can I pass a variable to the without() filter?

Tags: theming

I would like to replace `'field_body', 'field_link'` with a variable.

I am using the following code.

```
{{ content|without('field_body', 'field_link') }}
```

What I really want is passing a single string containing the names of those two fields, as in the following code, which doesn't work.

```
{% set foo = "'field_body', 'field_link'" %}
{{ content|without(foo) }}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: Far easier to do some preprocess in this scenario IMO.

Comment: Now that Drupal has Twig in templates, a theme shouldn't need to use PHP in preprocess. But array handling is a weak point of Twig and Drupal still has so many arrays instead of objects. So in this case yes, this is easier to do in preprocess.

Comment: I take you need to do something different than what you show here, because with two literal strings like those, I don't see how using a single literal string would be better. It would be better you show what you are really trying to achieve, rather than giving a simplified version.

Comment: I would like to be able to include the same field values into multiple templates, like `{% include 'partial.html.twig' with {'var': foo} %}`, which seemed like it should be possible, but doesn't appear to work.